# VLSM network subnetting and expanding of ip range

Tags: networking, cisco, vlan, subnet

I have a subnet/vlan which is almost full I want to expand it basically my layout currently is  below:

VLAN ID Useable IP Range            Network Mask

10  192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.14 255.255.255.240

20  192.168.1.17 to 192.168.1.30    255.255.255.240

30  192.168.1.33 to 192.168.1.62    255.255.255.224 - need to expand as full

40  192.168.1.65 to 192.168.1.78    255.255.255.240

50  192.168.1.81 to 192.168.1.94    255.255.255.240

60  192.168.1.97 to 192.168.1.110   255.255.255.240

70  192.168.1.113 to 192.168.1.126  255.255.255.240

90  192.168.1.145 to 192.168.1.158  255.255.255.240

Spare   192.168.1.160 to 192.168.1.175  255.255.255.240

Spare   192.168.1.177 to 192.168.1.190  255.255.255.240

VLAN 30 is the one I am running out of space. thankfully vlan 40 and 50 which is right after that is assigned but very few host and i can easily change their ips.

So my new plan is to expand vlan 30 to a /26 from /27

VLAN ID Useable IP Range            Network Mask

10  192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.14 255.255.255.240

20  192.168.1.17 to 192.168.1.30    255.255.255.240

30  192.168.1.33 to 192.168.1.93    255.255.255.192 -expand and change mask

60  192.168.1.97 to 192.168.1.110   255.255.255.240

70  192.168.1.113 to 192.168.1.126  255.255.255.240

80  192.168.1.129 to 192.168.1.142  255.255.255.240

90  192.168.1.145 to 192.168.1.158  255.255.255.240

40  192.168.1.160 to 192.168.1.175  255.255.255.240

50  192.168.1.177 to 192.168.1.190  255.255.255.240

so will it work for the above reconfig? Thanks

Cheers

Comment: drw, are you actually using this IP range? If so is there a reason why you are stifling what addresses you  use from this private network range? Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't work, you have to steal from vlan 10 and 20.

192.168.1.33/27 aka 192.168.1.33 255.255.255.**224** ( not the 240 you mention ) allows the ip range you showed.

192.168.1.33/26 aka 192.168.1.33/255.255.255.192 your usable range would be 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.62